# Choosing the right geo reference system - NorthEast Atlantic

Tags: coordinate-system

I am currently trying to calculate fish stock density for various stocks in the NE Atlantic. My habitat areas are too large to use UTM and I was wondering how I would find the best geo-coordinate system to use? My area covers the entire FAO fishing area 27. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

I have changed the meridian as suggested see screenshot. Does this mean that I simply need to change the '10' figure in order to define any new longitude as the central meridian? In other words, currently the central meridian is '10' but if i wanted it to be 15, I simply have to edit this in?

Lambert equal area projection
[image]

Saving new CRS projection

[image]

Meta Data tab of warped tiff:

[image]

Raster --> Projections --> Warp

[image]

Comment: If you want to work with both meridians, you should create two custom CRS. Just exchanging the value does not automatically reproject all coordinate values.

Comment: Ok, how do i get the system to re-project all the coordinates? Currently, it appears to me to be registering the new prime meridian of 10 (see the test section in the new screen shot above), is this correct? Also fyi I would be using separate Qgis projects for every new custom CRS.

Comment: Supposed your original coordinates are in WGS84 lat/lon: Load the data with EPSG:4326, then rightclick -> `Save As ...` to a new name and the custom CRS. **Do** **not** use `Set CRS for layer`, it will **not** reproject the coordinates.

Comment: Do you mean 'save as' for the entire project or each individual layer once they are all loaded? This is the process I have followed: 1. loaded the raster which is in EPSG:4326. 2. Selected 'settings' --> 'Custom CRS' --> entered the following into the 'parameters' field "+proj=sinu +lon_0=10 +x_0=False Easting +y_0=False Northing" and clicked ok --> Then right clicked the layer in question and next to the 'CRS' field clicked 'change' and selected the Custom CRS and clicked 'ok'.

Comment: That's the wrong one. You have to save the layer to another file and CRS, add that to the canvas, and remove the old one. The Custom CRS also goes to `Project -> Project Properties`, CRS tab; with `On-the-fly-reprojection` enabled.

Comment: so i have done the following: right click raster layer --> 'save as' --> in the CRS field clicked 'change' --> selected my custom CRS, clicked ok. Then I went to load the new Tiff file i just created however it came up with an error message saying 'invalid data source'. I have loaded a new image titled 'saving new CRS projection' in the question for your reference. Ps.  yes on the fly is enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17285/discussion-between-anina-and-andre-joost).

Answer (score 3):

You are interested in density, so equal-area projection would be the most appropriate. However, your area is tricky because you have the pole + some low latitude (<40). (My first impression was to use a [Lambert Azimuthal Equal area projection for North Atlantic](http://georepository.com/crs_3574/WGS-84-North-Pole-LAEA-Atlantic.html) but you are out of range). Therefore,a global projection is probably what you need.

I suggest the sinusoidal projection. You could customize it a bit by setting its central meridian in the middle of your area (around 10°). You can edit the proj 4 description file of your custom sinusoidal.

> +proj=sinu +lon_0=**10**
>                +x_0=False Easting
>                +y_0=False Northing

Comment: I have set the layer projection to EPSG 54008 world_sinusoidal. Can you please advise how to set the primary meridian? Additionally, is it reasonable to change the position of the primary meridian for each stock habitat area I am calculating (i.e. move the meridian in the middle of each new habitat area i am looking at)?

Comment: It depends if you want to make a global map at the end (keep central meridian to 0), or not (you will have less shape distortions if you change the position of your central meridian)

Comment: I just want to calculate individual habitat areas so no I do not want a global map at the end. So in other words I should change the position of my central meridian for each new area I calculate?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest choosing a lambert equal area projection, centered roughly in the middle of your fishing zone:

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=60 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

which looks like this:
[image]

Comment: This would include the entire area so it looks great. Is your suggested path '+proj=laea +lat_0=60 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs' already centered to the middle of my zone? Do i enter this path into the parameters field found at: 'settings' --> 'custom CRS'? Please see new screen shot added above titled ' lambert equual area projection'

Comment: The layer you show covers the whole world. Unfortunately, laea is not valid for the antipodal point, giving you error messages. So you better clip your data roughly to the hemisphere you are interested using degree borders before reprojecting to laea. My projection is centered on 0°E 60°N. You can change that with different lon_0 and lat_0 values.

Comment: OK I clipped the region to basically represent what you showed in the map but I am still receiving error message. Is my map not allowed to cross the 0 degree longitude boundary?

Comment: I am not sure about restrictions for raster files using `Save as...`.  Can you try `Raster -> Projections -> Warp`?

Comment: Ok i did that. How do I know if the file has actually been converted, seeing as that every time I import a file to Qgis it it asks for the CRS which i obviously set to the my target CRS. How do I know the coordinates have actually been changed?

Comment: Additionally , the output file does not have any extension (i.e. does not show .tiff at the end of it), is this a problem?

Comment: To proof the reprojection, look at the extent in the properties, Metadata tab. For degrees, the extent is limited by +/-180/90. Btw, clipping to 89.9 degrees North might solve some problems. Adding .tif to the filename manually would be a good idea.

Comment: I included screenshot of my metadata tab in the question. The layer seems to be in my custom Lambert CRS. The extents has not changed however. Is this correct? Thankyou!

Comment: The extent in your screenshot looks still like degrees. It should be xMin,yMin -7826939.43;-3897114.90 : xMax,yMax 5559098.10;2217061.97 in laea centered on 70°North.

Comment: Dam so it hasn't converted. What am i doing wrong? I have edited in a screen shot of my 'warping' page.

Comment: If it is the same file as mentioned above, you have corrupted it with `Set CRS for layer`. Maybe setting source_SRS to EPSG:4326 can fix it, else re-add the file to the canvas.

Comment: I have just retried this entire process. I redownloaded the data (but this time as a geotiff using grid registered data as opposed to the original cell registered data). I used the 'saved as' function to set the layer to my custom lambert projection as discussed. And then readded it. However the same this has occured, the Layer Extent (layer original source projection) is still as follows. 
-12391163.6335219126194715,-11350420.2286790478974581 : 12391163.6335219088941813,12724434.0868199747055769 . I am not sure what is happening but i feel like my only option left is to use default WGS84.